# External libraries work just fine in a .html file but not in a quasar project

Tags: html, vue.js, leaflet, react-leaflet, quasar-framework

I'm trying to move my code in an .html file to a Quasar project. The code works perfectly fine when I run my .html file but I receive errors from Quasar.
Here is my initial code in the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Neshan Map Example (Leaflet)</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://static.neshan.org/sdk/leaflet/1.4.0/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://static.neshan.org/sdk/leaflet/1.4.0/leaflet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 450px; background: #eee; border: 2px solid #aaa;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myMap = new L.Map('map', {
        key: 'myKey',
        maptype: 'dreamy',
        poi: true,
        traffic: false,
        center: [36.320378,59.571256],
        zoom: 14
    });
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?{foo}', {foo: 'bar', attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'}).addTo(myMap);
    var marker = L.marker([36.320378,59.571256]).addTo(myMap);
    var popup = marker.bindPopup('<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.');
    popup.openPopup();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The below code is my index.vue:

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center">
    <link href="https://static.neshan.org/sdk/leaflet/1.4.0/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://static.neshan.org/sdk/leaflet/1.4.0/leaflet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 450px; background: #eee; border: 2px solid #aaa;">></div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myMap = new L.Map('map', {
        key: 'myKey',
        maptype: 'dreamy',
        poi: true,
        traffic: false,
        center: [36.320378,59.571256],
        zoom: 14
    });
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?{foo}', {foo: 'bar', attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'}).addTo(myMap);
    var marker = L.marker([36.320378,59.571256]).addTo(myMap);
    var popup = marker.bindPopup('<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.');
    popup.openPopup();
</script>
```

I received this error from the browser:

> Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as `<script>`, as they will not be parsed

I also tried this:

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center">
    <link href="https://static.neshan.org/sdk/leaflet/1.4.0/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 450px; background: #eee; border: 2px solid #aaa;">></div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    import * as Vue2Leaflet from 'vue2-leaflet'
    var myMap = new L.Map('map', {
        key: 'myKey',
        maptype: 'dreamy',
        poi: true,
        traffic: false,
        center: [36.320378,59.571256],
        zoom: 14
    });
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?{foo}', {foo: 'bar', attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'}).addTo(myMap);
    var marker = L.marker([36.320378,59.571256]).addTo(myMap);
    var popup = marker.bindPopup('<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.');
    popup.openPopup();
</script>
```

Even though I don't get any error from the code above, the map does not appear in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's not Quasar, it's Vue itself that removes tags with side-effects (Quasar is a framework built on top of Vue.js).

Also, you are importing Vue2Leaflet, which has the leaflet library as a dependency, but still using the js and css files from cdn and not the Vue2Leaflet library.

My suggestion:

1. Run `npm install leaflet` in your project (if you don't have leaflet listed in package.json)
2. Remove Vue2Leaflet from package.json and the import statement completely, as Vue2Leaflet is just a wrapper around the leaflet library.
3. Remove the link and script tags INSIDE the template tag.
4. Outside the template tag, in the script tag, do:

```
import L from 'leaflet'

export default {
  mounted () {
   // move your code here
  }
}
```

I was able to render the map with these changes, without errors, but looking a mess.

Last step would be to add `<link href="https://static.neshan.org/sdk/leaflet/1.4.0/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` to the index.template.html file in the `src` folder of your project.

I am using quasar version 1.4.5.

Keep in mind that with Quasar Framework you have entered the world of Vue.js where things work differently than plain HTML and JS files. Read the documentation for both on their respective homepages. https://vuejs.org/ and https://quasar.dev/. If you need help getting started there are some good courses listed on the Vue homepage (under the Learn menu).

I hope this helps.